# Combine Layered Navigation and search by name in Magento 2.4

Tags: php, magento2, layered-navigation

I am trying to add a searchbox on my category pages that my users can use to filter (by name) the products in category that they are looking at. It should also work with already existing filters that's already supported by Layered Navigation.

I've tried using a plugin and hooking into `afterGetProductCollection`, but it doesn't work. Here's what I've tried:

**di.xml:**

```xml
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
    <plugin name="LayerPlugin" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Layer"/>
</type>
```

**Layer.php**

```php
public function afterGetProductCollection($subject, $collection)
{
    $search = $this->request->getParam('q');
    if ($search) {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', ['like' => '%' . $search . '%']);
        $collection->getSize();
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

If I don't include `$collection->getSize()` it seems to only filter on the first page.

There's a few things that still doesn't work even after adding the `getSize` statement though:

- I am forever stuck on page 1 - it's impossible for me to navigate to further even when setting the page number directly in the URL.
- The last page number is incorrectly calculated in the pager.

Thank you